# Is there a way to sort an object that has multiple attribute types by a single type?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an animal model with the following attributes.

```
name: string
sex: string
acquired_at: datetime
fed_at: datetime
groomed_at: datetime
played_with: datetime
slept_at: datetime    
sold_at: datetime
```

and I want to display the column with the most recent datetime, but only for the fed, groomed, slept, and play columns, which will be constantly changing with the most recent times. Is there a way to get the object like `Animal.last` and get the column with the most recent datetime out of the 4 columns?

Right now I just have an if statement that checks the 4 columns against each other but it seems long and unnecessary.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". It's important to show your effort in solving the problem. What have you written toward solving this? SO isn't a "write my code" site, it's for helping fix the problem in the code you wrote, so showing us the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem is essential.

Comment: I wonder if making each event a row in a separate table would make this easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to know which column is the oldest, the most recent time value out of the four columns, you can simply use `max` to choose it from the record `attributes` converted to hash:

```
Animal.last.attributes.values_at("fed_at", "groomed_at", "slept_at", "played_with").max
# => Thu, 07 Apr 2016 00:18:04 CEST +02:00
```

If you DO need to get the latest value from the four columns as well as the column name, you can use `max_by` to select the latest key-value pair from the `attributes` hash:

```
Animal.last.attributes.
    slice("fed_at", "groomed_at", "slept_at", "played_with").
    max_by{ |k,v| v }
# => e.g. [ "groomed_at", Thu, 07 Apr 2016 00:18:04 CEST +02:00 ]
```

This will return an array with the first item the attribute name and second item is its value, which is the latest time.

Answer (score 1):

```
Animal.all.sort_by{|a| [a.fed_at, a.groomed_at, a.slept_at, a.played_with].max}.last
```

Comment: Formatting is very important for readability. Also, tossing out code with no explanation doesn't help nearly as much as explaining *WHY* the code is usable and what it does. It's like teaching someone to fish vs. tossing them a fish. We want them to know how to avoid the problem in the future too.